# Trying to make a server with sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm trying to make a chat app in Python and I'm having some trouble.
I made a server on which I can connect successfully by using the local IP address. However, when I try to connect to it on an another device with my public IP address, there seems to be a timeout, no errors occur and it's continuously trying to connect.

Edit: I've already set up port-forwarding for my IPv4 address. And the client is using the public IP.

server.py:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 2000
s.bind((host, port))
print("Server started, waiting for incoming connections")

s.listen(5)
connection, address = s.accept()

print("New connection from", address)

while True:
    data = connection.recv(1024).decode()
    print("received:", data)
    ret = data + "+++++++"
    connection.send(ret.encode())
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = #my public ip address from whatsmyip.com
port = 2000
s.connect((host, port))
print("Connected.")

while True:
    message = input("msg: ")
    s.send(message.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
```

Comment: @abarnert yes, I think it is an internal address. That command is placing a string of the IPv4 address in the host variable. Is there a workaround?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, if you've got port forwarding from the public address to the private one, and your client is using the public address.

Comment: Next thing: What platform are you on? Any firewall settings that could be relevant?

Comment: @abarnert I'm using Windows 7 and I've completely disabled firewall.

Comment: [edit] that into the text of your question. Also explain that you set up port forwarding, that the client is using the public address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, is your server in a network with other devices? If you have a router there, the IP you see in whatsmyip.com is the router's, not your computer's, IP. So you'd be trying to connect to it.

You can check that with the command *netstat*.

Comment: No, the server isn't in a network with other devices. The netstat command is giving me the same IP as the `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` command does.